# How to create a column requiring more than 50 different factor values with dplyr

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am using ifelse statements more than 100 times to create >100 visit categories as shown in below .

```
df<-data.frame(visit_time=c(12,20,70,100),city=c("X","X","X","X"))

df$visit_category<-ifelse(df$visit_time>=0 & df$visit_time<12 ,"0-12",ifelse(df$visit_time>=12 & df$visit_time <20,"12-20",ifelse(df$visit_time>=20 & df$visit_time <50,"20-50",ifelse(df$visit_time>=50 & df$visit_time <100,"50-100",">100"))))
```

As shown in sample data [ visit category column] , I have 4 different values for sample data , and I need to create >50 different categories on actual data.

When I try to create more than 50 categories , I get an error in R like this [ Did some research n found out that R does not allow more than 50 iflese statements at the same time !!, Dont know if its true ]

> Error: unexpected ')' in
>
> Error: contextstack overflow at line 42

Is there any better way to create >50 different visit category values other than using ifelse statements in R ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function `cut()`, with its argument `breaks =` to define your own intervals.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    category = visit_time %>% cut(breaks = c(12, 20, 50, 100, 1e6), include.lowest = T, right = F),
    category = fct_recode(category, '100+' = '[100,1e+06]')
  )

  visit_time city category
1         12    X  [12,20)
2         20    X  [20,50)
3         70    X [50,100)
4        100    X     100+
```

Comment: I tried using the code in sparklyr ,but I am getting an error like . I thought we can assume same code in sparklyr .                                                                                
 Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'AS' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 75)

Comment: `fct_recode` is from `forcats` package, try `forcats::fct_recode(category, '100+' = '[100,1e+06]')`

Comment: indeed, I added `library(forcasts)` at the beginning. You could also load the library tidyverse if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for information and I used the updated code, but it di not work for sparklyr as it uses ft_bucketizer to create bins in Spark ,though I did not find any example of this ...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the `cut()` function, one alternative is to use a **loop** with an **if statement** testing the conditions of your buckets, instead of using directly the function `ifelse()`.

```
df$category <- NA

breaks_limits <- c(0, 12, 20, 50, 100, 1e6)
breaks_labels <- c('[0-12]', '[12-20]', '[20-50]', '[50-100]', '100+')
breaks_num <- length(breaks_labels)

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  for(b in 1:breaks_num)
  {
    if(df$visit_time[i] >= breaks_limits[b] & df$visit_time[i] < breaks_limits[b+1])
      df$category[i] <- breaks_labels[b]
  }
}
```